# Postman hangs when sending "POST" request to API

Tags: node.js, typescript, post, postman, hapi

So i'm using Postman and i need to send a POST method request to my api but every time i do it hangs even if the handler does nothing except return a simple value. I'm using hapi so the syntax might differ a little bit from the standard express app.

**currency.ts**

```
//this is where i define the route methods and paths

import * as Hapi from "hapi";
import IRouteArea from "../server/IRouteArea";
import CurrencyController from "../controller/CurrencyController";
import hapiAuthJwt2 = require("hapi-auth-jwt2");
import { join } from "lodash";
import { RESOLVER } from "awilix";

const CurrencyArea = ({ currencyController }: any): IRouteArea => {
  let _controller = currencyController as CurrencyController;
  return {
    registerRoutes(server: Hapi.Server) {
      server.bind(_controller);
      
      server.route({
        method: "GET",
        path: "/api/currencies",
        options: {
          auth: {
            mode: "try"
          },
          plugins: { "hapi-auth-cookie": { redirectTo: false } },
          handler: _controller.getCurrencies
        }
      });
      server.route({
        method: "POST",  // this one is causing me problems
        path: "/api/currencies/{id}",
        options: {
          auth: {
            mode: "try"
          },
          plugins: { "hapi-auth-cookie": { redirectTo: false }},         
          handler: _controller.editCurrency
        }
      });
    }
  };
};

export default CurrencyArea;
```

and even though the actual handler of the request isn't doing anything special...

**CurrencyController.ts**

```
//here i define the handlers of requests sent to routes in the previous file

import * as Hapi from "hapi";
import { name } from "mustache";
import GetCurrencyListInteractor from "../../interactor/currencies/GetCurrencyListInteractor";
import Task from "../../runtime/Task";

export default class CurrencyController {
  private task: Task;

  constructor({ task }: any) {
    this.task = task;
  }

  public async getCurrencies(
    request: Hapi.Request,
    h: Hapi.ResponseToolkit
  ): Promise<any> {
    try {
       return this.task.start<GetCurrencyListInteractor>(
        "getCurrencyList",
        t => t.execute()
      ); 
    } catch (error) {
      return error as any;
    }
  }
  

  public async editCurrency( //it's supposed to just return the parameter sent in the url
    request: Hapi.Request,
    h: Hapi.ResponseToolkit
  ): Promise<any> {
    try {
      return request.params.id;
    } catch (error) {
      return error as any;
    }
  }
}
```

it always hangs and gets stuck on the "sending request" screen when i send the request. One interesting thing is that the exact same route works as intended but only if the method defined in *currency.ts* is "GET". If i leave everything else the way it is and change the method from "GET" to "POST" or "PUT" or "PATCH" it stops working.

[this goes on forever](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGgeH.png)

Comment: It doesn't even look like valid JS/TS. to me. Are you sure this runs ? I'd if I'm missing something but `return { func(foo) { } }` isn't valid.

Comment: NVM, til my syntax would return an object with propertyname `func` and value the function. Didn't realize this shorthand existed.